# Multiple machines on the same network getting the same IP lease via DHCP

Tags: networking, 18.04, vmware, dhcp

I am creating 18.04 machines on vmware with two network interfaces. 192.168 and 10.100.

I have a ubuntu vm set up as a dhcp server for both networks - I am having a serious problem with the DHCP because different machines - with different MAC addresses are getting the same IP address.

In the list below you can see that 192.168.1.206 has been issued to 4 machines!

It is especially weird because the DHCP on the router was getting a similar problem. I have never seen anything like this before.

Ta,

Andrew

```
ubuntu@admin-workstation:~/git/kubeone$ dhcp-lease-list
To get manufacturer names please download http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/oui.txt to /usr/local/etc/oui.txt
Reading leases from /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
MAC                IP              hostname       valid until         manufacturer        
===============================================================================================
00:50:56:01:00:00  10.100.0.201    WIN-69FSNR02U2 2020-02-18 17:42:40 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:04:35  192.168.1.206   andrew-4-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:40:34 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:15:a3  10.100.0.203    andrew-4-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:38:57 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:88:d1  10.100.0.202    andrew-3-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:45:06 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:98:6d  192.168.1.206   andrew-2-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:39:13 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:a0:37  192.168.1.206   pappsabi-0-cp- 2020-02-18 17:41:17 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:cc:d4  192.168.1.206   andrew-3-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:41:51 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:e8:40  10.100.0.202    pappsabi-0-cp- 2020-02-18 17:41:21 -NA-                
00:50:56:86:eb:44  10.100.0.200    andrew-2-cp-1  2020-02-18 17:48:21 -NA-    



ubuntu@admin-workstation:~/git/kubeone$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:86:f3:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.150/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe86:f3c7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:86:70:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.0.150/24 brd 10.100.0.255 scope global ens224
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe86:70bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


ubuntu@admin-workstation:~/git/kubeone$ arp -a
? (10.100.0.214) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.202) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.205) at 00:50:56:86:cc:d4 [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.212) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.254) at 00:09:0f:09:08:22 [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.200) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.219) at 00:50:56:86:6c:42 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.206) at 00:50:56:11:11:01 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.217) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.204) at 00:50:56:12:12:01 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.214) at 00:50:56:86:fd:c2 [ether] on ens192
? (192.168.1.202) at 00:50:56:86:25:50 [ether] on ens192
? (192.168.1.200) at 00:50:56:86:98:6d [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.211) at 00:50:56:86:eb:44 [ether] on ens224
host01.scrat.local (192.168.1.1) at a0:d3:c1:f6:45:78 [ether] on ens192
? (192.168.1.206) at 00:50:56:86:cc:d4 [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.209) at 00:50:56:86:eb:44 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.204) at 00:50:56:86:98:6d [ether] on ens192
vc01.scrat.local (192.168.1.10) at 00:0c:29:b1:99:34 [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.215) at 00:50:56:86:eb:44 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.203) at 00:50:56:86:eb:44 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.218) at 00:50:56:86:15:a3 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.213) at 00:50:56:86:eb:44 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.201) at 00:50:56:01:00:00 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.216) at 00:50:56:86:6c:42 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.207) at 00:50:56:12:12:01 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.205) at 00:50:56:86:61:e3 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.220) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.203) at 00:50:56:86:cc:d4 [ether] on ens192
_gateway (10.100.0.254) at 00:09:0f:09:08:22 [ether] on ens224
? (10.100.0.210) at 00:50:56:86:88:d1 [ether] on ens224
? (192.168.1.201) at 00:50:56:86:cc:d4 [ether] on ens192
dc01.scrat.local (192.168.1.101) at 00:0c:29:69:5f:f5 [ether] on ens192
? (10.100.0.208) at 00:50:56:86:61:e3 [ether] on ens224



ubuntu@admin-workstation:~/git/kubeone$ sudo cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf | grep -v "#"

option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers                  192.168.1.254;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        option domain-search            "scrat.local";
        option domain-name-servers      192.168.1.101;
        range   192.168.1.200   192.168.1.220;
}

subnet 10.100.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers                  10.100.0.254;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        option domain-name-servers      10.100.0.254;
        range   10.100.0.200   10.100.0.220;
}
```

Comment: Your `arp -an` shows duplicate MAC addresses. The DHCP server uses MAC addresses to differentiate among systems. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: Arp shows us the local broadcast domain - a mapping of IP addresses and their last known mac address. Duplicate macs in the ARP just means that a specific mac had more than one IP address in the life of that arp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason - DHCP does not work like it did in the old days. Rather than MAC address based ubuntu is sending /etc/machine-id - an alphanumeric string which is generated on boot.

It seems that I was getting the problem because of a duplicate /etc/machine-id on my machines - They were all cloned from the same image which had this value set.

Machines cloned from an other clean image do not suffer from the problem.

If you run into this problem just zero the file `> /etc/machine-id` - don't delete it or everything will break!

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 the following command seemed to create a new id systemd-machine-id-setup.

You may still need to manually delete /etc/machine-id